# in python, how to check if list is not empty, and empty it if so?

Tags: python, list, empty-list

I've seen several answers about how to check if list is empty, but didn't find excatly what i need.
shortly - in python, I need a way to check if list is full, and then empty it, but i need that the check will start just after i fill the list.

I'm define list by call my class - Packet()

```
class Packet(object):
"""description of class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.newPacket = []
newPacket = Packet()
```

I have menu, which one of the options is to call function in the class to fill the list.
but, if the function get chose again, i need to empty the instance, and start a new one.
I've tried to do that:

```
if newPacket:
    del newPacket
newPacket.MakePacket()
```

but this don't let me start the list by call the function..
if i disable the

```
if newPacket:
    del newPacket
```

the function works just fine.

Comment: This is not C and you should not be managing deletion of objects.

Comment: using the same name `newPacket` in example for internal list and class instance  is misleading. You ask how to delete list but you delete class instance.

Comment: to be clear, i want to empty the instance (list in this case), and to apllay a new class instance with the same name.. of course it's not deleting like c..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be confusing a particular `Packet` instance that you have created and chosen to name `newPacket`, with its attribute of the same name. Rather than delete the instance, or even delete the list, it sounds like you want to empty the list. Because you've given two different things the same name, the list in question is now accessible from your command-line as `newPacket.newPacket` (although which the object itself likes to refer to it, in its own methods, as `self.newPacket`).

So. When you `del newPacket`, you are removing the reference to the object `newPacket` from the current workspace.  The interpreter will then raise a `NameError` if you try to do anything with that symbol, such as `newPacket.MakePacket()` - because that variable no longer exists in the current workspace.

If you want to implement `Packet` methods that count the items in the `self.newPacket` list attribute, or empty it, you could say:

```
class Packet(object):

    # ...

    def count( self ):
        return len( self.newPacket )

    def clear( self ):
        del self.newPacket[:]
```

That incidentally illustrates one way of emptying a list, while retaining a reference to the now-empty list:   `del myList[:]`

Comment: its actually just reducing the ref-count by one ... but this is close enough for me :P

Answer (score 1):

```
values = input("Enter a list (U CAN ALSO CREATE AN EMPTY LIST. IF YOU WANT THEN SIMPLY PRESS 'ENTER'). If not then write e.g. ABC or 1, 2 or 2019 to insert: ")
list = list(values)
if list == []:
    print("Your list", list, "is an empty list!")
else:
    print("Your list", list, "is not an empty list.")
```

Firstly, it'll take an input from user. Secondly, after giving the input it'll check the given input. Finally, after the checking process completion it'll give a msg to the user (will show a msg if the given input empty or not? Whatever the scenario is).

Comment: This is a code only answer, which is considered bad quality in SO. Please elaborate what this snippet does and how it helps with the problem.

Comment: I added explanation. Hopefully, you will understand.